# The Format DateTime it increase 1 year more

Tags: php, datetime, format

I'm use this code:

```
$my_date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i', '20/02/2018 00:51')->format('Y-m-d H:i');
echo $my_date_time;
```

the code should show me this: `2018-02-20 00:51`

**but show:** `2019-02-20 00:51`

it increase 1 more year.. why..?

Comment: You're mapping the day as month. That's why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you reversed the day and the month when using `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Try this format:

`d/m/Y`

```
$my_date_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '20/02/2018 00:51')->format('Y-m-d H:i'); echo $my_date_time;
```

[Test online](https://3v4l.org/j1mG3)